# How do I list my friends using FQL?

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I am attempting to list all of my friends' birthdays using the Facebook-SDK version 6.1.4
When I use the code below (that is without FQL, it works well, but I cannot get the birthdays, just the name and id values).

```
 var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
    dynamic me = client.Get(myusername);
    client.IsSecureConnection = true;
    friendListData = client.Get("/" + me.id + "/friends?fields=name,id");
    JObject job = JObject.Parse(friendListData.ToString());
```

So I attempted to use the code with FQL and it throws an exception.

```
    var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
    client.IsSecureConnection = true;
    dynamic me = client.Get(myusername);
    //var id = me.id;


    Facebook.JsonObject friendListData = new Facebook.JsonObject();
        try
        {
            friendListData = (Facebook.JsonObject)client.Get("fql",
                new
                {
                    q = new
                    {
                        name = "SELECT name, birthday, email, uid FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND birthday_date != 'null' ORDER BY birthday_date"
                    }
                });
        }
        catch (FacebookOAuthException facebookAuth)
        {
    //"(OAuthException - #102) A user access token is required to request this resource."
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _Is_ your access token a _user_ access token? (And btw., you can also get the birthday via “normal” API query, it does not have to be FQL.)

Comment: I have used the following URL to generate the access_token. It is an APP access token. 

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &grant_type=client_credentials

Comment: CBroe, I think you have pointed me in the right direction. The token that I need to use should be a user access token and not an app access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if the access_token is being set and print it, then check it in the debugger.

For the FQL call,

This is based on common letters within the months, specifically *a*, *e* and *u*. From that one can do strpos to match these.

`SELECT name, birthday, email, uid FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND (strpos(lower(birthday),"a") >=0 OR strpos(lower(birthday),"e") >=0 OR strpos(lower(birthday),"u") >=0) ORDER BY birthday_date`

This should pull out all nulls as `null` doesn't contain any letters (by definition of null, not the letters itself)

Comment: I put a break point in the code. I am able to see the access token.

Comment: @abhi, that answers half the question. No do the second half of what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with Windows PowerShell and http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com:

import-module facebook
$FB_DefaultExtendedPermissions += "friends_birthday"
New-FBConnection
Get-FBFriend -Fields name,birthday | select name,birthday

I should add "friends_birthday" to the list of default permissions...